# WPF xaml Designer View Gives System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception

Tags: wpf, xaml, exception, visual-studio-2013

VS2013; full install on Windows 8.1 (upgraded from 8.0)

So the designer can't load any xaml controls what so ever and gives this error. I've reinstalled VS at least 8 times with a full removal of almost all programs on my system.

Ironically a fresh install on a VM of 8.1 (no upgrade) lets VS work just fine and I can view xaml files in the designer.

I've tested this on brand new projects with nothing in them and my existing application as well.

Does anyone know of this error? Google didn't really point me too far. I also have "My Documents" on another drive and the temp folder on C:. Before 2013 and 8.1 everything worked fine in 8.0 and VS2012. I have pasted the error below.

```
  System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
  Invalid window handle
     at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.NativeMethods.GetClassName(IntPtr hwnd)
     at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ModalSynchronizer.IsModalWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
     at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ModalSynchronizer.UpdateWindowDisabling(IntPtr hwndActive, IntPtr hwndLastActive)

  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
  Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
     at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
     at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
     at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
     at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
     at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
     at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
     at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
     at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
     at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
     at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
     at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
     at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
     at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
     at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
     at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
     at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
     at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
     at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
     at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
     at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
     at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.DesignerProcess.RunApplication()
     at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.DesignerProcess.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Main>b__0()
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```